# Select interaction: toggle only when clicking feature

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have set up a ol3 map with a single vector layer where the features are distinguished by a `type` attribute. I have added a select interaction that only selects/unselects features with `type == 'cp'`. So far I have:

```
selectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.click,
    filter: function (feat, layer) {
        return (feat.get('type') == 'cp');
    }
});
```

What I want now:

- When a feature of type 'cp' is clicked, its selection is toggled (without affecting any other selection)
- Select multiple features without holding down the shift key
- Selection must NOT be cleared if the click occurs where there is no
  feature of type 'cp'

Please help with how to implement this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following to the select interaction's options is giving the desired behaviour:

```
toggleCondition: function (mbe) {
    return (mbe.type == 'click');
}
```

Comment: Note that this is identical to `toggleCondition: ol.events.condition.click`. Also, please mark you answer as accepted if your issue is solved.